# Get id parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have function that start working when I click on `parent` and get `parent id` ( `tmp` ), but when I click on `child` my function works too but return `undefind`. How to get `parent` `id` doesn't matter on what I click `child` or `parent` or other elemnts in `parent` div ?

```
<div class="parent" id="tmp">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```js
'click .parent': function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).attr("id")); // from MeteorJS framework , but same sense
}
```

Comment: Where's your JS code? In theory if you attach the event handler to the `#tmp` element, it won't matter which element you click on as the event will bubble up the DOM.

Comment: Check the class of the clicked element. If it's parent, return parent id. If it's not parent, call jquery method parent(), or parents() if the element is doubly nested, and find the element with class parent.

Comment: because the target is what you actually click....

Comment: You can use "hasClass", $(e.target).hasClass("parent").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your click handler you should use `this` to refer to the element that is handling the event:

```
'click .parent': function(){
    console.log(this.id);
}
```

By using `e.target` you're targeting the element which originated the event - which in the cases you describe would be the `.child` element which has no `id` attribute.

If you are unable to use the `this` keyword due to restrictions imposed by Meteor, you could instead use the `currentTarget` property on the `event`, as it should have the same effect:

```
'click .parent': function(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id); // or $(e.currentTarget).prop('id')
}
```

Comment: in Meteor `this` not return js dom element, or smth in this way, so I can't use your method, only can work with `e` (`event`)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('.parent').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  //console.log($(this)[0].id)
});
```

or

```
$('.parent').click(function(e){
  console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

or

```
$('.parent').click(function(e){
  console.log(e.delegateTarget.id);
});
```

Comment: I can't use `this`, because it's return another things, so I can work only with `event` or `e` (how in my example)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');
    
    if (typeof id === 'undefined') {
        //return current element as this is a parent
        console.log($(e.target).attr('id'));
    } else {
        //return parent's id 
        console.log(id);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" id="tmp">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And when you click on the parent?

Comment: updated, it now returns an id not class of a parent element

Comment: Now it should handle `red`. There isn't much requirments mentioned by the user about restrictions.